# Is there anyway to include an If/Then statement in my query?

Tags: sql

Write a query to break down the groups by ratings, showing the count of groups with no ratings, as well as a count of each of the following ranges: 1-1.99, 2-2.99, 3-3.99, 4-4.99, and 5.

Note: If a group has no ratings, its rating will appear as "0" in the ratings column of the grp table.

Use a CASE WHEN  or IF/THEN statement to categorize the ratings.

So far I have

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN rating between '1-1.99')
FROM grp;

But I get error code 1064 SQL syntax, any help with be much appreciated. [ERD TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm74O.png)

Comment: The correct approach generally tends to be contextual, and based on how complex and volumous the underlying tables are. If the required join and row-count are high, the optimal SQL statement can often be something other than the obvious one. Try benchmarking a compound case, and also a UNION of separate queries and see what might work best for your dataset.

Comment: Select round(rating,0), count(*) from grp group by round (rating,0)

Comment: Should we assume the column type is `decimal(X, 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question although you have not mentioned any sample data and required sample output:
What you should do is use `CASE-WHEN` statements to put your values into specific ranges and group by these ranges.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN rating BETWEEN 1 AND 1.99 THEN '1-1.99'
WHEN rating BETWEEN 2 AND 2.99 THEN '2-2.99'
WHEN rating BETWEEN 3 AND 3.99 THEN '3-3.99'
WHEN rating BETWEEN 4 AND 4.99 THEN '4-4.99'
WHEN rating =5 THEN '5'
ELSE '0' END) AS ranges,
COUNT(*) AS rangeCount
 FROM grp
 GROUP BY ranges
```

Comment: Are you able to explain how you got to the "ELSE '0' END)" I would not have known what to do for this

Comment: I assume that your ranges stay between 1 and 5, the rest is 0. "If a group has no rating its 0"

Comment: Don't use "between" for this. Case returns the first match. This statement breaks when the rating is 2.995. better: case when x<1 then 0 when x<2 then 1 else 3 end as ranges. A CTP os optional, you can directly group by expressions.

Comment: @realbart, Your comment makes so much sense. Thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes minor things are overlooked. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use common table expression (CTE).
Something like:

```
with cte as 
    (SELECT 
    rating,
    (CASE WHEN rating BETWEEN 1 AND 1.99 THEN '1-1.99'
    WHEN rating BETWEEN 2 AND 2.99 THEN '2-2.99'
    WHEN rating BETWEEN 3 AND 3.99 THEN '3-3.99'
    WHEN rating BETWEEN 4 AND 4.99 THEN '4-4.99'
    WHEN rating =5 THEN '5'
    ELSE '0' END) AS ranges
    FROM grp)
select 
    ranges,
    count(ranges)
from cte
group by ranges;
```

The output should be like:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2BWU.png)